# ACRA put user email in crash report

Tags: email, acra

How can I fill the USER_EMAIL field with ACRA crash reporter?

The report starts with:

USER_EMAIL = N/A

Answer (score 2):

To set the USER_EMAIL field edit your SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ACRA.getACRASharedPreferences();
prefs.edit().putString(ACRA.PREF_USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, user).commit();
```